On Atiyah-Macdonald proposition 3.11(iv)

The prime ideal of $S^{-1}A$ are one-to-one correspondence with prime ideals of $A$ that doesn't meet $S$

In book they proved that every extension $P^e$ of prime ideal $P$ is prime iff it doesn't meet $S$ , I cannot see why this gives the one-to-one correspondence. Here I can see prime $Q$ in $S^{-1}A$, $Q^{c}$ doesn't meet $S$, namely a well defined map $P\mapsto P^e$, but why is this map injective, in other words why every $P$ doesn't meet $S$ is contracted? I think they miss a step to use iii) to show that these $P$ are contracted.
And at end of proof, the arthour write:

by i) (all ideal of $S^{-1}A$ is extended), $S^{-1}P=S^{-1}A$ iff $P$
meets $S$.

I cannot see why i) implies this?

It would be better if your quotes were actually quotes and not your version!

Indeed we need iii) to get this one-to-one correspondence.

iv) If $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal in $S^{-1}A$, then $\mathfrak q^{c}$ is a prime ideal in $A$ (this much is true for any ring homomorphism). Conversely, if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal in $A$, then $A/\mathfrak p$ is an integral domain;if $\bar S$ is the image of $S$ in $A/\mathfrak p$, we have $S^{-1}A/S^{-1}\mathfrak p=\bar S^{-1}(A/\mathfrak p)$ which is either $0$ or else is contained in the field of fractions of $A/\mathfrak p$ and is therefore an integral domain, and therefore $S^{-1}\mathfrak p$ is either prime or is the unit ideal; by i) the latter possibility occurs if and only if $\mathfrak p$ meets $S$.

I think here ''by i)'' should be ''by ii)'', which states that

ii) If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal in $A$, then $\mathfrak a^{ec} = \bigcup_{s\in S}(\mathfrak a:s)$. Hence $\mathfrak a^e = (1)$ if and only
if $\mathfrak a$ meets $S$.

From above we know that $S^{-1}\mathfrak p$ is a prime iff $\mathfrak p$ does not meet $S$. By i) we know that every prime $\mathfrak q$ of $S^{-1}A$ can be written as $S^{-1}\mathfrak p$ for some $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec} A$.

iii) $\mathfrak a$ is contracted iff no element of $S$ is a zero-divisor in $A/\mathfrak a$.

Since $A/\mathfrak p$ is an integral domain, any $\mathfrak p$ that does not meet $S$ is contracted. So $\mathfrak p^{ec}=\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak p\mapsto \mathfrak p^e$ is injective.

By the way, some textbooks about commutative algebra have rather a lot of gaps, just regard them as exercises. ; )

I have one question: in iii) are we viewing $A/\mathfrak{a}$ as quotient ring or $A$-module? In former case, iii) should have been $s+\mathfrak{a}$ is not zero divisor for all $s\in S$.

For surjectivity, we also have to use ii) along with i). Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be prime ideal in $S^{-1}A$. In particular $\mathfrak{q}\in E$ by i), and hence $\mathfrak{q}^{ce}= \mathfrak{q}$. Then $\mathfrak{q}^c$ is prime ideal such that $\mathfrak{q}^c\cap S=\emptyset$ [otherwise $\mathfrak{q}^{ce}=(1)=\mathfrak{q}$ by ii)]. Thus $\mathfrak{p}= \mathfrak{q}^c\mapsto \mathfrak{q}$.

@user264745 thanks for your completement to the surjectivity part. In iii) it should be the first case you mentioned. Here is the proof: $\mathfrak a$ is contracted iff $\mathfrak a^{ec}\subseteq \mathfrak a$ iff ($as\in \mathfrak a$ for some $s\in S$$\implies$$a\in\mathfrak a$), which is equivalent to say that $s\in S$ is $A/\mathfrak a$-regular.

Thank you so much for the clarification. Author didn’t define notion of zero divisor on a module. I am using wikipedia definition. For surjectivity part, I think your original answer is precise. We know $S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathfrak{p}\cap S=\emptyset$. $\Leftarrow$ is used for map $\mathfrak{p}\mapsto \mathfrak{p}^e$ to be well defined. $\Rightarrow$ and i) is used for surjectivity.

Let $P$ be prime ideal of $A$ such that $P\cap S=\emptyset$. Then $P^e$ is a prime ideal, since $(a/s)(b/t)\in P^e\Rightarrow ab/st\in P^e\Rightarrow ab/st=p/s' \text{for some }p\in P\text{ and }s'\in S\Rightarrow t'(s'ab-atp)=0 \text{ for some }t'\in S\Rightarrow t's'ab=t'atp\in P\Rightarrow ab\in P\Rightarrow a\in P\text{ or }b\in P\Rightarrow a/s\in P\text{ or }b/t\in P$.
Define $\phi:T\longrightarrow T'$ by $\phi(P)=P^e$ where $T$ be the set of all prime ideals of $A$ that doesn't meet $S$ and $T'$ be the set of all prime ideals of $S^{-1}A$.
Let $P$ be an ideal of $A$ such that $P^e$ is prime ideal of $S^{-1}A$. Then $P$ is prime, since $ab\in P\Rightarrow ab/1\in P^e\Rightarrow a/1\in P^e\text{ or }b/1\in P^e\Rightarrow a\in P\text{ or }b\in P$ (Likewise previous paragraph). Clearly $P\cap S=\emptyset$, for otherwise $P^e=A$. So $\phi$ is onto.
Now let $P^e,P'^e$ be prime ideals of $S^{-1}A$ such that $P^e\subseteq P'^e$. Let $a\in P$. Then $a/1\in P^e\subseteq P'^e\Rightarrow a\in P'$. So $P\subseteq P'$. Therefore $P^e=P'^e\Rightarrow P=P'$. So $\phi$ is clearly injective.
Thus there exists one-one correspondence between the set of prime ideals of $A$ that doesn't meet $S$ and the set of all prime ideals of $S^{-1}A$
